# How to encrypts the data using sql encryption while inserting a data through java

Tags: java, mysql

I am a beginner,i want to encrypts the data using sql encryption while inserting a data through java.And  i want to do query sum calculation of that encrypt data. is that possible

Comment: Since [MySQL's SQL encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html) would make use of functions you define in the query you should just do that. If you have any difficulties doing that you should show us what you've got so far. Calculating a sum of the encrypted data would need some sort of decryption and that again is probably done within the query.

Comment: BEGIN
     DECLARE returnhourrate DOUBLE;
 SELECT IFNULL(fn_getmonthlysalary( empID,dates),0) /(SELECT  SUM(actualHour)  FROM `vwt_projectdetailslist` WHERE  employeeid=empID AND  MONTH(dates)
   AND YEAR(dates)) INTO returnhourrate  ;
     RETURN returnhourrate;
     
    END$$
i have this function it calls another

Comment: BEGIN
DECLARE monthlyEarningss DOUBLE;
SELECT  monthlyEarnings INTO monthlyEarningss  FROM t_employeeoffice  WHERE t_employeeoffice.employeeID=empid  
  AND activeStatus=1 AND witheffectfrom<=wdate ORDER BY withEffectFrom DESC LIMIT 1;
  RETURN monthlyEarningss;
    END$$

Comment: i try tried to encrypt salary by using base64 bt it not useful because in my database function cant use that encrypted data

Comment: Instead of pasting that much unformatted code into a comment, consider [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Mysql
for More Refer to followinf [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)

To insert Encrypted data.

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('root', AES_ENCRYPT('somepassword', 'key12346123'));
```

To Read Decrypted data

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password, 'key12346123') FROM users WHERE username = 'root';
```

Comment: is it posssible using hibernate

Comment: could it possible without  using native query . and using hibernate

Comment: @jermiya you might want to add that additional twist to your question. As it is there's not even the slightest indication you're using anything other than JDBC. That being said, yes it _is_ possible, albeit probably not out-of-the-box. You might have to provide your own db dialect (extend the one you're using) to add functions to HQL that map those encryption and decryption functions to SQL.